# Is it safe to use a Stripe secret api key inside an Android app?

Tags: android

I've seen a few people on here suggesting it's okay to do it this way. It seems much easier, but couldn't someone decompile your app and compromise your key?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You should never put your secret key inside your mobile app. As you suspect, it'd be very easy to retrieve your key. Once an attacker has your key, they can basically do anything with your account: charge your existing customers, issue refunds, etc.

From the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android#using-tokens):

> (For security purposes, you should never embed your secret API key in your app.)

Comment: Where is the best place to put the API key?

Comment: @user2312688 You should have a backend server that will send API requests to Stripe. The only part of the payment flow that is done directly in the mobile app is the tokenization of the customer's payment information, which is done using your publishable API key. Once the token is created, you'd then send it to your backend server where you can use it in API requests sent with your secret API key.