# Security risks to expose stripe key with read balance privileges to client?

Tags: security, client, stripe-payments

Is it bad practice to expose a read only key on the client for reading customer balances? I suppose the ideal would be to place it on the backend, but implementing it on the client would be much easier for me. What is the typical perspective for a read-only key with limited privileges being exposed to the client? I'm under the impression the limited privileges makes it a non-risk for being exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically found this answer: [Is it safe to use a Stripe secret api key inside an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394752/is-it-safe-to-use-a-stripe-secret-api-key-inside-an-android-app) though the answer quote from stripe docs seems outdated:

> (For security purposes, you should never embed your secret API key in your app.)